# Get music from WP8

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, stream, audio-player

I can get a song using this code:

```
 MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
 SongCollection sc = ml.Songs;
 Song song = s[0];
```

But `song` only contains metadata information (artist, name, album, genre, etc.), no URI or the name of the music file.

I need a byte stream of the music file, how do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Tough luck

this property is not available and there is no way to stream the song as well
maybe in the future, MSFT will expose this property